# oracle How to count duplicate values with restriction

Tags: sql, oracle

```
river country province
a1        b1        c1    
a1        b1        c2

select river, count(province)
from geo_river
group by river
having count (province) > 10
```

like this, I know how to count river cross more than 10 province, but I don't know

what to do to count river cross more than 10 province that is in the same country..

I need to add some restriction, but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just by changing the `group by`:

```
select river, count(province)
from geo_river
group by river, country
having count(province) > 10;
```

Feel free to include `country` in the `select` clause as well.